# remix.ethereum.org - you cannot test payable methods

Tags: remix, payable, bug, remix-tests

I am using: https://remix.ethereum.org

contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Receiver {

    receive() external payable {}

    function getMoney() public payable {}

}
```

tests

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "../contracts/Receiver.sol"; // Import the EventTicketing contract
import "remix_tests.sol"; 

contract TestReceiveEtherExample {
    Receiver public instance;

    function beforeEach() public {
        instance = new Receiver();
    }

    function checkBalance() public {
        uint256 balance = address(instance).balance;
        Assert.equal(balance, 0, "Initial balance should be 0");
    }

    function testReceiveEther() public payable {
        // Send 1 ether to the contract
        payable(address(instance)).transfer(1 ether);

        // Check if balance is updated correctly
        uint256 balance = address(instance).balance;
        Assert.equal(balance, 1 ether, "Balance should be 1 ether after receiving");
    }

    function testGetMoney() public payable {
        uint256 initialBalance = address(instance).balance;

        // Call the getMoney function
        instance.getMoney{value: 1 ether}();

        uint256 finalBalance = address(instance).balance;

        // Check if the balance has increased by 1 ether
        Assert.equal(finalBalance, initialBalance + 1 ether, "Balance should be increased by 1 ether after calling getMoney");
    }
}
```

result of running tests:
[image: tests_outpyut]

calling functions directly on deployed smart contract works perfectly fine:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you send value when deploying the contract? Here is a picture of where you need to include the value when deploying:

[image]

Comment: yes, calling contract directly works perfectly fine (as I described in the main post) 

only when running unit tests - some tests are failing (some, not all)